# String index out of range and invalid syntax

Tags: python

Trying to make my code print out a random string of 40 characters from the letters, T, C, G and A.
Which has a 50% chance to change one of the characters into something else. When I try to run it, all it says is string index out of range

```
def generateDNASequence():
    listOfGenomes = ["T", "G", "C", "A"]
    for i in range(40):
        dnaSequence=(random.choice(listOfGenomes))
        print(dnaSequence,end="")
    return dnaSequence
def applyGammaRadiation(dnaSequence):
    pass
    chance=random.randint(0,100)
    if (chance>=50):
        placeInDNA = random.randint(0, 40)
        if (dnaSequence[placeInDNA]=='T'):
            listOfGenomes=["G", "C", "A"]
            randomGenome = (random.choice(listOfGenomes))
            mutatedSequence=dnaSequence.replace(randomGenome,dnaSequence[placeInDNA])
            return mutatedSequence
        elif(dnaSequence[placeInDNA]=='G'):
            listOfGenomes = ["T","C", "A"]
            randomGenome = (random.choice(listOfGenomes))
            mutatedSequence = dnaSequence.replace(randomGenome, dnaSequence[placeInDNA])
            return mutatedSequence
        elif(dnaSequence[placeInDNA]=='C'):
            listOfGenomes = ["T", "G", "A"]
            randomGenome = (random.choice(listOfGenomes))
            mutatedSequence = dnaSequence.replace(randomGenome, dnaSequence[placeInDNA])
            return mutatedSequence
        elif(dnaSequence[placeInDNA]=='A'):
            listOfGenomes = ["T", "G", "A"]
            randomGenome = (random.choice(listOfGenomes))
            mutatedSequence = dnaSequence.replace(randomGenome, dnaSequence[placeInDNA])
            return mutatedSequence
    elif(chance<50):
        return dnaSequence
def detectMutation(dna1, mutatedDna):
    length=len(dna1)
    mutation=0
    for x in range(length):
        dna2=dna1[x-1]
        dna3=mutatedDna[x-1]
        if dna2==dna3:
            print(" ")
        else:
            print("^")
            mutation+=1
        if mutation>0:
         print("mutation Detected")
        else:
            print("no Mutation Detected")
dnaSequence=generateDNASequence()
mutatedSequence=applyGammaRadiation(dnaSequence)
detectMutation(dnaSequence,mutatedSequence)
```

Comment: Have you done any debugging? I would recommend reading https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/. As an aside, I'm pretty sure `generateDNASequence` will return a single genome, not a list of 40.

Answer (score 1):

```
for x in range(length):
        dna2=dna1[x-1]
        dna3=mutatedDna[x-1]
```

`x` starts from 0. So `dna1[x-1]` will throw an error

Comment: I don't think it's the cause. Don't forget Index of -1 is legal in python. So it won't throw any Error.

Answer (score 1):

You should change this line of code `placeInDNA = random.randint(0, 40)` in `applyGammaRadiation` function to `placeInDNA = random.randint(0, 39)`.
As the length of your DNA sequence string is 40, `random.randint(a, b)` will return a random integer N such that a <= N <= b.